# File keeps coming back vb net

Tags: vb.net, caching

I am in process of building a basic chat client using an ftp server as it's host.

To update the chat log, it downloads a file, reads it, adds it to the log on a new line and finally the file is deleted itself. After that the cycle starts again.

But what happens is the when the cycle starts for the 2nd time, it somehow recreates the contents of the previous file even if the file on the server has changed.

This is the part that seems to act funny:

```
Private Sub bg_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bg.DoWork

    Dim url As String = ("http://vknyazev.0fees.us/message.txt")
    Dim fwc As New WebClient
    fwc.DownloadFile(url, "log.txt")
    Dim freader As New StreamReader("log.txt")
    message2 = freader.ReadToEnd
    freader.Close()
    freader.Dispose()
    IO.File.Delete("log.txt")


End Sub
```

[Here is the full solution (starts download from dropbox in .zip file)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/104410405/client.zip)

Comment: I suspect it is due to a cache issue but cannot be sure

Comment: might be. have a look at the `CachePolicy` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening due to a caching issue. The most simple workaround would be to add a random value somewhere inside the url.
Such as `http://example.com/file.txt?44351`